# How to pass all objects attributes to ListView

Tags: python, django

This is my detail view, I pass if a post is 'liked' and 'total likes' in context. I want to do the same in my List View for every object.

```
class MemeDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Meme
    template_name = "memes/meme_detail.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        meme = get_object_or_404(Meme, id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        context['total_likes'] = meme.total_likes()


        liked = False
        if meme.likes.filter(id=self.request.user.id).exists():
            liked = True

        context['liked'] = liked
        return context
```

here is my ListView:

```
class MemeListView(ListView):
    model = Meme
    paginate_by = 100
    ordering = ['-created_at']

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['now'] = timezone.now()

        return context
```

How can I pass all objects 'total likes' and 'liked' to context?

Comment: Show your template for your `MemeListView`

Comment: The same way, only that now you can't just return a value for `liked` and one for `total_likes`, but you need a dictionary in which the keys are an identifier for the memes, and the values are those `liked` and `total_likes` for the corresponding meme.

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the total likes and liked for paginated Meme like this:

```
class MemeListView(ListView):
     # rest of the code

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['now'] = timezone.now()
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        meme_likes_list = list()

        for meme in queryset:
            like_data = dict()
            like_data['total_likes'] = meme.total_likes()
            like_data['liked'] = meme.likes.filter(id=self.request.user.id).exists()
            meme_likes_list.append(like_data)

        context['meme_likes'] = meme_likes_list
        return context
```

Comment: @HubertBudny If this fixed your isse you can mark it as accepted.